# Django Permission denied: '/media/images' uploading image

Tags: django

Please help. I'm trying to follow along with the following tutorial https://wsvincent.com/django-image-uploads/
I am getting the permission denied error as soon as I attempt to post the djangopony.png image in the section. I'm using Ubuntu 19 and Django 2.1.5.

My virtual environment and project are located in the direcotry 
/home/sgoodman/insta

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── insta_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── images
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── posts
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 sgoodman sgoodman   4096 Apr 30 13:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 sgoodman sgoodman   4096 Apr 30 13:50 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 sgoodman sgoodman 135168 Apr 30 13:53 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 2 sgoodman sgoodman   4096 Apr 30 13:50 insta_project/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sgoodman sgoodman    545 Apr 30 12:57 manage.py*
drwxrwxrwx 3 sgoodman sgoodman   4096 Apr 30 13:46 media/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sgoodman sgoodman    176 Apr 30 12:56 Pipfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 sgoodman sgoodman   3914 Apr 30 12:56 Pipfile.lock
drwxrwxr-x 3 sgoodman sgoodman   4096 Apr 30 13:46 posts/
```

MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL setting in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself in the end.

When running on the development machines, I am in fact running using my current user's privileges. However, when running on the deployment server, I am in fact running through `wsgi`, which means it's running using `www-data`'s privileges.

`www-data` is neither the owner nor in the group of users that own `/var/www`. This means that `www-data` is treated as `other` and has the permissions set to others.

The **BAD** solution to this would be to do:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/
```

This would give everyone full access to everything in `/var/www/`, [which is a very bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777).

Another **BAD** solution would be to do:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/
```

This would change the owner to `www-data`, [which opens security vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65201/20064).

The **GOOD** solution would be:

```
sudo groupadd varwwwusers
sudo adduser www-data varwwwusers
sudo chgrp -R varwwwusers /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 760 /var/www/
```

This adds `www-data` to the `varwwwusers` group, which is then set as the group for `/var/www/` and all of its subfolders. `chmod` will give read, write, execute permissions to the owner but the group will not be able to execute any script potentially uploaded in there if for example the webserver got hacked.

You could set it to `740` to make it more secure but then you won't be able to use `Django's` `collectstatic` functionality so stick to `760` unless you're very confident about what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have a /var/www directory. I'm running the pipenv from /home/sgoodman/insta

Comment: create env with sudo